# Getting a 404 using App Harbor and BitBucket

Tags: model-view-controller, connection-string, bitbucket, appharbor

I'm new to AppHarbour and I'm trying to deploy my MVC app on a free account.

I keep getting a 404 error.

The app is coming from Bit-bucket and it was deployed successfully. 
In my Hostnames section i see the following

[image]

[image]

so i have added the following to the Hosts file in my machine: 
176.34.122.158      camelotfaultmanagement.apphb.com

but i still get a 404 ..

What am i doing wrong ? 
And a follow-up question how can i edit one of the files to be able to edit the connection ?string to my DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may not have any successful builds yet - You have to push to Bitbucket to trigger your first build. You can see a list of builds on the app dashboard: https://appharbor.com/applications/camelotfaultmanagement

To use the built-in .apphb.com domain, you don't have to mess with any DNS setup.